# How to identify lines from clusters of points?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, autoencoder, dbscan

I'm constructing an autoencoder to reduce the dimensionality of a combustion data set from 17 to 2.

[image: Three observable lines]

As the figure above shows, there are certain trends - you can see about three lines. I want to separate the data (unsupervised) into line clusters, for which future test data can be associated with, and am struggling to find a way to do this.

I've had a look at DBSCAN as a hierarchal clustering method (e.g. as [here](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_hdbscan_works.html)). I am not sure if it suitable but my code fails at this point:

```
palette = sns.color_palette()
cluster_colors = [sns.desaturate(palette[col], sat)
                  if col >= 0 else (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) for col, sat in
                  zip(clusterer.labels_, clusterer.probabilities_)]

plt.scatter(z[0], z[1], c=cluster_colors, **plot_kwds)
```

where `z[0]` and `z[1]` are the two dimensions of the the clustered data. The error is:

```
'ValueError: 'c' argument has 100 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 2, 'y' with size 2.'
```

If you have suggested alternatives please let me know. In addition, my data is large (> 1 million points in cases).

Answer (score 0):

You need to plot one cluster at a time.

Matplotlib does not accept an array of colors, unfortunately.

Hence it complains about the `c` parameter.

P.s. *why* reduce to 2 dimensions? Have you tried clustering the original 17 dimensional space? At 2 dimensions, with a nonlinear map, you may have lost too much.

Comment: How can one interpret a 17 dimensional cluster? As far as I am aware, clustering is about minimising some form of another of distance (e.g. Euclidean distance). Is this not meaningless at such high dimensions?

Comment: 17 is not particularly high when it comes to distances. You can even still use a scatterplot matrix etc.